# isc-dhcp-server and dnsmasq is not working in Virt Manager(debian) KVM

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, kvm

I am trying to make a DHCP server in a VM what I pass a PCI ethenet adaptor to.
with dnsmasq I get the "interface ens7 does not exist"
dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=ens7
port=53
```

I tryed isc-dhcp-server but i get

```
No subnet declaration for ens7(no Ipv4 addresses)
*** Ignoring reqests on ens7
```

/etc/dhcp/dhcpcd.conf

```
authoritative;
subnet 10.254.239.0 netmask 255.255.255.224{
 range 10.254.239.10 10.254.239.20;
}

Thanks

I try both dnsmasq and isc-dhcp-server
```